# Can I set up Redis to publish to a pub/sub channel when a key-value is changed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, publish-subscribe

Can I set up Redis to publish to a pub/sub channel when a key-value is changed?

Is there anyway to monitor these changes automatically or do I just need to build it in a part of the set to broadcast the new value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That sort of thing is too complex/not generic enough to be built in to redis, but it is easier to do as part of your client anyway - just send a PUBLISH command after the SET.

Note that unlike SUBSCRIBE, PUBLISH does not require a dedicated connection so is easily integrated with other commands.

Answer (score 6):

As of Redis 2.8.0, there is support for KeySpace Notifications, which do exactly what you want. You can read more about it here - http://redis.io/topics/notifications

KeySpace notifications are a little cpu intensive, so are disabled by default. For simpler tasks, doing what @tom-clarkson said above should suffice.

Comment: This should be the top answer!